# How to deploy a rails app to google container engine with kubernetes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have tried many method to build my rails app to a docker image. And deploy it to google container engine. But until now, no one success.

My Dockerfile(Under rails root path)

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock
ADD vendor/gems/my_gem $APP_HOME/vendor/gems/my_gem
ADD init.sh $APP_HOME/

RUN export LANG=C.UTF-8 && bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME

CMD ["sh", "init.sh"]
```

My init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

My kubernetes config file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/my-project-id/myapp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http-server
        env:
          - name: RAILS_ENV
            value: "production"
```

After I create web controller on gke with kubectl:

```
kubectl create -f web-controller.yml
```

and see the pod logs:

```
kubectl logs web-controller-xxxxx
```

it shows:

```
init.sh: 2: init.sh: bundle: not found
init.sh: 3: init.sh: bundle: not found
```

It seems the path not found. Then how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kubectl exec to enter your container and print the environment.
http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/getting-into-containers.html

For example:
kubectl exec web-controller-xxxxx sh -c printenv

You could also use kubectl interactively to confirm that bundle is in your container image:

kubectl exec -ti web-controller-xxxxx sh

If bundle is in your image, then either add its directory to PATH in init.sh, or specify its path explicitly in each command.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should execute your `init.sh` directly instead of `sh init.sh`? It would appear that the `$PATH` and maybe other ENV variables are not getting set for that `sh init.sh` shell. If you can `exec` into the container and `which bundle` shows the path to bundle, then you're losing your login ENVs when executing with `sh init.sh`.

If it helps at all, I've written [a how-to](https://medium.com/@jbielick/rails-on-kubernetes-8cd4940eacbe) on deploying Rails on GKE with Kubernetes. One thing you may want to change is that if you have several of your web pods running, they will *all* run the `init.sh` script and they will *all* attempt to `db:migrate`. There will be a race condition for which one migrates and in what order (if you have many). You probably only want to run `db:migrate` from *one* container during a deploy. You can use a [Kubernetes Job](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/) to accomplish that or `kubectl run migrator --image=us.gcr.io/your/image --rm --restart=Never` or the like to execute the `db:migrate` task just once before rolling out your new web pods.